# A city which is not familiar to me

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives

Help me please convey the sense correctly. I am not sure that 'unknown city' is correct. I want to describe the city which I am going to visit for the first time. I am not familiar with this city.

unknown city, city unknown to me, unfamiliar city?

Comment: An unfamiliar city. Though if you can give us a fuller context, we can perhaps suggest a better phrasing. In many contexts, "... a city I hadn't visited before" or "a city I hadn't been to" might be more common.

Comment: The context: I am going to attent a meeting in the city which is unknown to me. @Jim Reynolds why are you using the past perfect? Can I use the present perfect or the simple past?

Comment: You can say, <City> is unfamiliar to me.  I am unfamiliar with <City>.  I have a meeting in <City>- I've never been there before so I'm unfamiliar with it.  OR you can say, I've never been there so I don't know my way around.

Comment: I agree with @Jim – certainly the city is not _unknown_ to you; otherwise, you wouldn't be going there :^) You can even use the word _new_: _The city is new to me_. Most would understand that to mean that you hadn't visited the city before.

Comment: Did anyone notice we are Jim Reynolds, Jim, and J.R.? I am all of those. We can give you even more information with more specific context. Speech or writing? Are you informing someone about a future plan? Describing a past event? Formal or informal? Etc. Past perfect could be a description of a past event: I went to London last month. I had not been to London before that.

Comment: You can use any verb tense, depending on the situation and what you want to express. A future plan, informal, conversational: I'm going to a meeting in Rome. I've never been there before. / It's my first time there. / It will be my first visit to Rome. / I'm going to Moscow. I've never seen Moscow.

Answer (score 1):

While *unknown* and *unfamiliar* **both** mean the same in this context, I think, the latter one has *some flair* of being personalized. If you say 'unknown', I'm afraid it **may** be generalized.

Maybe, because 'unfamiliar' has come from the word 'family', someone's family? 
Taking a *human* example makes it clearer --It's possible that I *know* Sam, but I'm not 'familiar' with him. I don't know how he is. In other words, I *know* Sam, he's Kelly's brother; but, I'm not familiar with him; so whether you do business with him, it's your take. Don't consider my opinion on that!

Also, if something is 'unknown', it might be unknown to the world; but if something is 'unfamiliar', you immediately make things personal? Unfamiliar to *someone?*

> I'm visiting an unknown city ~ *"Oh really, which corner of the world it is in?"*

over...

> I'm visiting an unfamiliar city ~ *I see, better read it on WikiTravel and go*.

This makes me think. If you are visiting 'unknown' place, you *may* not find any information about it, but if you are *unfamiliar* with some place, you may have some information. I'm not *familiar* with New York City, but The Big Apple is not *unknown* to me!

But again, as I see, both the words have been used in this context. My answer is just a try to get subtlety of it.

But yes, if you *define* that it's unknown to ***me***, it works!